# MassTransit generates _skipped queues which I want to ignore

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Can anyone guess what the problem can be because I'm clueless on how to solve this. MassTransit generates **_skipped** queues and I don't have a clue why it is generating those. It is being generated when doing a publish request response.

Request Client is created using following method in MassTransit.RequestClientExtensions

```
public static IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse> CreatePublishRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(this IBus bus, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan? ttl = null, Action<SendContext<TRequest>> callback = null) where TRequest : class where TResponse : class
{
  return (IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>) new PublishRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(bus, timeout, ttl, callback);
}
```

And Request is done as follows:

```
TResponse response = TaskUtil.Await(() => requestClient.Request(request));
```

As you can see this is Request Response scenario where Request is being sent to all consumers. But because at the moment we have only one consumer it only is being sent to that consumer. deadletters appear easily if a publishrequestresponse is done to multiple consumers, once a consumer responds, the other consumer doesn't know where to respond and a deadletter is generated. But because we have one consumer here, we can eliminate this possibility.

So what could be other reasons for these skipped queues? Huge thanks for any help on how I can troubleshoot this...

I have to say, in the Consume method, in some condition, we raise a `RequestTimeoutException` and catch it in the requesting application. This is tested and this doesn't generate skipped queues.

Comment: Just to clarify for other people who read this question. RabbitMQ is *not* generating the queues with the `_skipped` suffix - it must be either Mass Transit or the user's code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skipped queue is a dead letter queue. It means that your endpoint queue has a binding to some message exchange but there is no consumer for that message any longer. Maybe you change the topology and moved the consumer. You can go to the RMQ management UI and check the bindings for your endpoint exchange. If you look at messages that ended up in the skipped queue, you will find out what message types to look for.

Exchanges are named after message types so it will be easy to find the obsolete binding.

Then, in the management UI, you can manually remove the binding that is obsolete and there will be no more messages coming to the skipped queue.

Comment: I just checked the bindings and every message type causing skipped queues only has one binding. which looks good...

Comment: Have you been able to find out the wrong binding? There is no magic there, if there is a consumer for that message type in the endpoint, and messages get processed, or messages come and MT has no consumer for it and messages end up in the dead letter (skipped) queue.

Comment: If you're using the request client, and the client-side has timed out (before receiving a response/fault from the service), a subsequent response/fault to that request would end up in the skipped queue. Be sure to set the TTL (expiration) of the response messages so that they don't live longer than the timeouts.