# How to configure MassTransit so that commands in queue waiting for the consumers?

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a question about MassTransit configuration.
There is a Main application and Microservice.
For example, the Main application sends a commands to the microservice(consumer) to write off funds from the account.

Configuration in the Main application:

```
var rabbitHost = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/app");
services.AddMassTransit(x => {
  x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => {
    var host = cfg.Host(rabbitHost, hostConfigurator => {
      hostConfigurator.Username("user");
      hostConfigurator.Password("password");
    });
  }));
});
EndpointConvention.Map<WithdrawFunds>(new Uri(rabbitHost + "/test-queue"));
```

Microservice configuration:

```
var rabbitHost = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/app");
services.AddMassTransit(x => {
  x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => {
    var host = cfg.Host(rabbitHost, hostConfigurator => {
      hostConfigurator.Username("username");
      hostConfigurator.Password("password");
    });
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test-queue", ep => {
      ep.Consumer<WithdrawFundsConsumer>();
    });
  }));
});
```

Command executed in Main application like:

```
await _sendEndpointProvider.Send<WithdrawFunds>(new {
  Amount = 100,
  AccountId = "someId"
});
```

MassTransit creates a "test-queue" queue and if both applications are running, then the interaction works successfully. But if I stop the microservice, then a 
"test-queue_skipped" queue is created in which the missed messages fall. However, if I start the Microservice, it will not receive missed messages.

How can I configure MassTransit so that "_skipped" is not created, and messages are waiting for the consumer to appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ generates \_skipped queues which I want to ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161172/rabbitmq-generates-skipped-queues-which-i-want-to-ignore)

Comment: If your messages are being moved to the `_skipped` queue, you have a receive endpoint configured that does not have the consumer configured. Are you creating more than one receive endpoint with the same queue name?

Comment: I know why messages get into the "skipped" queue - because I stop the consumer. I need to change this behavior. I want messages to accumulate in the queue even if there are no consumers. And when I start the consumer, It should receive all pending messages from the queue.

Comment: I think you're mistaken about why they get in there. If a message is in the skipped queue, Rabbit was able to deliver the message to the receiver endpoint but it was not processed or not processed successfully. You can look at the messages in Rabbit Management portal and see the MT-Reason: that it is in the _skipped queue. It is probably dead-letter.